# Twin Prime Formula

Tags: number-theory, factorial, integers, twin-primes

I have a function involving polynomials and the centre of the Binomial Triangle and I'd like to prove that the function produces a positive integer infinitely many times. I don't have any interest in what values the integers take so much, merely that they exist.

The function I have is:

$$f(n) = \dfrac{15n^5+23n^4-20n^3-56n^2-48n-16}{n^3(n+1)(n+2)^4}\begin{pmatrix}2n \\ n \end{pmatrix} + 4\dfrac{3n^2+6n+4}{n^3 (n+2)^3}$$

The only method I have thought of is that I could try to prove that $\sin\left(\pi f(n)\right)$ has an infinte number of roots. But that feels like kicking the can down the road as I don't know how to do that either!

Thank you for any and all help. Ben

---

Using partial fractions I get:

$$f(n) = \frac{\left( 4n^3+28n^2+84n+76 \right) \begin{pmatrix} 2n \\ n \end{pmatrix} - 2n-4}{(n+2)^4} - \frac{\begin{pmatrix} 2n \\ n \end{pmatrix} - 2}{n^3} - \frac{4\begin{pmatrix} 2n \\ n \end{pmatrix}}{n+1} $$

From here I can find conditions for each fraction separately.

$\frac{\begin{pmatrix} 2n \\ n \end{pmatrix} - 2}{n^3} \in \mathbb{N} \implies n \text{ is prime > 3   (I found this on A000984)}$

$\frac{4\begin{pmatrix} 2n \\ n \end{pmatrix}}{n+1} \in \mathbb{N} \implies n \in \mathbb{N} \text{  (Always true)}$

$$f(n) = \frac{\left( 4n^3+28n^2+84n+76 \right) \begin{pmatrix} 2n \\ n \end{pmatrix} - 2n-4}{(n+2)^4} - \color{Blue}{\frac{\begin{pmatrix} 2n \\ n \end{pmatrix} - 2}{n^3} - \frac{4\begin{pmatrix} 2n \\ n \end{pmatrix}}{n+1}} $$

---

This leaves the final condition:

$\frac{\left( 4n^3+28n^2+84n+76 \right) \begin{pmatrix} 2n \\ n \end{pmatrix} - 2n-4}{(n+2)^4} \in \mathbb{N} \\ \implies \left( 4n^3+28n^2+84n+76 \right) \begin{pmatrix} 2n \\ n \end{pmatrix} \equiv 2n+4\pmod{n^4+8n^3+24n^2+32n+16}$

This seems to hold true when $n+2$ is a prime.

---

So if this function outputs an infinite number of integers, the twin-prime conjecture should be true.
If $n$ is the lower of a pair of twin primes, then $f(n)$ is an integer.

Comment: I would start by rewriting those rational functions using partial fractions, to isolate the divisibility condition you need for each separate factor in the denominator.

Comment: I would expect the product of the fraction and the binomial coefficient to be an integer almost always, i.e. for all but finitely many values of $n$, whereas the other fraction can clearly only be an integer for finitely many $n$.

Comment: @Servaes: The first term is never an integer if $n$ is an odd prime (there is nothing to cancel the $n^3$ in the denominator).

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks Eric, I'll give that a go.

Comment: What makes you think that what you are trying to prove is true? Do you have any numerical evidence?

Comment: @Somos Ive checked up to n=60 and it works for some primes. Since there are an infinite number of primes I feel it would be more unusual if it didn't happen an infinite number of times.

Comment: @EricWofsey Any idea what I could do next?

Comment: I'm glad I read through to the last sentence before thinking about this. I very much doubt that there's a proof of the twin primes conjecture along these lines ...

Comment: @EthanBolker Oh go on Ethan, I'll go halves with you ;)

Comment: @BenCrossley how did you arrive at this formula?

Comment: @StudySmarterNotHarder I have no idea, sorry. It was something to do with Wolstenholme theorem.
If $C(n)$ are the centre entries of binomial triangle then I was considering $C(n+2) - C(n)$ and it's relationship to the Wolstenholme and Twin prime conjecture. Beyond that I have forgotten.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof that if both $n$ and $n+2$ are prime ($n>3$), then the output is integer: 
clearly it suffices to show that if $n+2$ is prime then $$ \left(4n^3+28n^2+84n+76\right)\binom{2n}{n} \equiv 2(n+2) \bmod{(n+2)^4}.$$
Let $p=n+2$ be prime, then this is equivalent to showing that: 
$$\tag1 2\left(p^3+p^2+5p-3\right)\binom{2p-4}{p-2} \equiv p \bmod{p^4}.$$

*Proof*

Since $n>3$, $p>3$ and by Wolstenhome's theorem we have:
\begin{align}  
\binom{2p-1}{p-1}&\equiv 1 \bmod p^3\\
p\binom{2p-1}{p-1}&\equiv p \bmod p^4\\
p\frac{2p-1}{p-1}\frac{2p-2}{p-2}\frac{2p-3}{p-3}\binom{2p-4}{p-4}&\equiv p \bmod p^4.
\end{align}

But $$ \binom{2p-4}{p-2}=\binom{2p-4}{p-4}\frac{p-1}{p-3}\frac{p}{p-2}.$$
Then
\begin{align}
p\frac{2p-1}{p-1}\frac{2p-2}{p-2}\frac{2p-3}{p-3}\frac{p-3}{p-1}\frac{p-2}{p}\binom{2p-4}{p-2}&\equiv p \bmod p^4
\end{align}
That is 
\begin{align}
\frac{(2p-1)(2p-2)(2p-3)}{(p-1)^2}\binom{2p-4}{p-2}&\equiv p \bmod p^4
\end{align}

But by doing the power expansion of $\frac{1}{(p-1)^2}$ , we see that 
$$ \frac{1}{(p-1)^2} \equiv 1+2p+3p^2+4p^3 \bmod p^4$$
and we are done since it is easy to see by expansion that $$(2p-1)(2p-2)(2p-3)(1+2p+3p^2+4p^3) \equiv 2(-3+5p+p^2+p^3) \bmod p^4.$$

I does seem that for the OP function to bring an integer, the argument must be the smallest prime of a twin prime pair. But proving this seems very difficult. What about trying to disprove it by computer search of a counterexemple ?